# Isomorphism $\varphi: S^{-1}A \to T^{-1}A$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $S \subseteq T$ be two multiplicative sets in a commutative ring $A$. I need to show that

> The homomorphism $\varphi: S^{-1}A \to T^{-1}A$,  $ \ a/s \mapsto a/s$ is an isomorphism iff any element of $T$ is a factor of some element in $S$.

If any element of $T$ is a factor of some element in $S$ then clearly $\varphi$ is surjective. Also, if $\varphi(a/s) = a/s = a'/s' = \varphi(a'/s')$, then $\exists t\in T$ such that  $t(as' - a's) = 0 $. But $dt = u \in S$ for some $d \in A$, so $u(as' -a's) = 0$ and hence $a/s = a'/s'$ in $S^{-1}A$. Therefore $\varphi$ is injective.

I am stuck with the proof for the other direction.
If $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, then for any $x \in T \setminus S$ we have $\varphi(a/s) = a/s = 1/x$ for some $a \in A$ and $s \in S$. This is equivalent to $t(ax - s) = 0 \Leftrightarrow tax = ts$ for some $t \in T$. Can I deduce from this equality that $x$ divides some $s$ in $S$?

Comment: It seems to me that you forgot the injectivity which says: if $ta=0$ for some $t\in T$, then there is $s\in S$ such that $sa=0$.

Comment: @user26857 $\varphi(0/1) = 0/1 = ta/1 = \varphi(ta/1) \ \Leftrightarrow \ \exists s \in S$ such that $sta = 0$. But how do you see, that $sa = 0$? Or you get it from another reasoning?

Comment: @user26857 ok, thank you. I think I got it. Then $\varphi(sa/1)  = sa/1 = sta/t = 0/t = 0/1 = \varphi(0/1)$ which means, that $ua = 0$ for some $u \in S$.

Comment: It would be nice to post your own answer in order to remove the question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $t(ax - s) = 0$ we have $$\varphi(0/1) = 0/1 = t(ax - s)/1 = \varphi(t(ax - s)/1).$$ Thus $0/1 = t(ax - s)/1$ in $S^{-1}A$ by injectivity of $\varphi$ and it is equivalent to $ut(ax - s) = 0$ where $u \in S$. This implies the following equality: $$\varphi(u(ax - s)/1) = u(ax - s)/1 = ut(ax - s)/t = 0/t = 0/1 = \varphi(0/1).$$ Again, using the injectivity of $\varphi$, we obtain $u(ax - s)/1 = 0/1$ in $S^{-1}A \Leftrightarrow \ \exists u' \in S$ such that $u'u(ax-s) = 0$. Since $S$ is a multiplicative set $v = u'u \in S$ and $vax = vs$. Therefore $x | vs \in S$ and hence $x$ is a factor of an element in $S$.